# Teshuvah Negating a Negative Prophecy

Tags: repentance-teshuvah, navi-prophets

There is a concept that while a positive prophecy *must* come to pass (at least when it is a national prophecy) a negative one can be retracted if the subjects to teshuvah (repent)? While there a number of places where this idea is found, I would like to know if anyone can identify a particular posuk (verse) in Sefer Yirmeyahu where I once saw this idea stated explicitly? (This isn't rhetorical, can't remember where it is anymore).

Comment: I remember seeing this idea illustrated recently in Daf Yomi. Maybe that will make your hunt easier. _Mod: This was written on the day Sanhedrin 91 was being studied._

Comment: an upvote for a name-appropriate question!

Comment: Appropriate for me, or appropriate for you? :)

Comment: possibly a useful source: http://www.dafyomi.org/index.php?masechta=shabbos&daf=55a

Answer (score 7):

[Jeremiah 28:8--9](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/i/t/t1128.htm#7)

ח הַנְּבִיאִים, אֲשֶׁר הָיוּ לְפָנַי וּלְפָנֶיךָ--מִן-הָעוֹלָם:  וַיִּנָּבְאוּ אֶל-אֲרָצוֹת רַבּוֹת, וְעַל-מַמְלָכוֹת גְּדֹלוֹת, לְמִלְחָמָה, וּלְרָעָה וּלְדָבֶר.  ט הַנָּבִיא, אֲשֶׁר יִנָּבֵא לְשָׁלוֹם--בְּבֹא, דְּבַר הַנָּבִיא, יִוָּדַע הַנָּבִיא, אֲשֶׁר-שְׁלָחוֹ יְהוָה בֶּאֱמֶת.  י

And see context in the preceding above verses.  Paraphrasing slightly: a different prophet just said "everything will be hunky-dory", to which Jeremiah replies "Amen, I hope you're right! ... May prophets including myself have prophesied calamities, only some of which have happened; only a prophecy for the good is carved in stone."

(Chief Rabbi Sacks discussed this in Shoftim 5769.  He quotes [Rambam's formulation of the concept in Chapter 10 of Yesodei HaTorah](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/i/1110.htm); hat tip to Machon Mamre for hyperlinking the citation to Jeremiah.)

Comment: See http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/18165389#18165389 et seqq.